# Send HTTP request to localhost

Tags: python, http, elasticsearch, flask, ubuntu-18.04

I'm building a Rest API with Flask. The API uses data from Elasticsearch that is running on localhost.

It is possible to send an HTTP request from Flask route to localhost?

Something like this:

```
@flashlog.route('/checkelasticisup')
def check_elastic_is_up():
    res = requests.get('http://localhost:9200/')
    return jsonify({'message': res.text})
```

I want to return to the client the Elasticsearch response that you get when you send GET request to localhost:9200:

```
{
  "name": "wEV_Spx",
  "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid": "dbPLLgYLRO69iYuT_pp4WA",
  "version": {
    "number": "6.3.0",
    "build_flavor": "default",
    "build_type": "deb",
    "build_hash": "424e937",
    "build_date": "2018-06-11T23:38:03.357887Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "7.3.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

For now, I'm getting:

> Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">

</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
```

How can I send an HTTP request to localhost (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)?
Thanks!!

Comment: replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`

Comment: comments are to clarify the question, not answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with my proxy configuration. Didn't configure the correct IP's to ignore.
After i added localhost, 127.0.0.1/8 and ::1 to the ignore host field in network settings om my Ubuntu machine, everything works.

Answer (score 4):

As @Metalik said, you must replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` for this to be able to work.

Comment: With 127.0.0.1 i get: Network Error (tcp_error) 

A communication error occurred: "Connection refused"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct port, and Elasticsearch is actually running?

Comment: Elastic is running. And I’m running my flask app on port 80 with my IP. Not on localhost:5000

Comment: Depending on how your elastic server is setup, the trailing slash in the request may be causing this @MeirKeller

Comment: i get the same result if or without that slash

Comment: If I run the same get request in the terminal I get a good response. I think the problem is something with flask.

Comment: I didn't yet found a solution for this. However the same code on a different computer works fine...

Comment: My bet is the problem resides in your elastic installation

Comment: Thanks for the help